# Guardar .csv en variable

Tags: bash, shell

Intento guardar un archivo .csv en una varible de esta forma:

```
variable=`archivo.csv`
```

pero me pone un error: archivo.csv:Command not found

Comment: ¿Cuando dices guardar te refieres al nombre o al contenido del archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso del "backtick" (o sea, el apóstrofe invertido: `` ` ``) en bash indica que se ejecute lo que va encerrado entre backticks y se sustitya por el resultado de la ejecución.

Por ejemplo:

```
variable=`whoami`
```

ejecutaría el comando `whoami` (que retorna el *username* del usuario) y deja ese nombre en la variable.

Así que en tu caso intenta ejecutar `archivo.csv` como si fuera un comando, y no es capaz.

Basta que uses comillas no invertidas. En este caso tanto `'archivo.csv'` como `"archivo.csv"` servirían (la diferencia es que dentro de unas comillas dobles como `"` puedes usar variables de entorno como `$PATH`, que serán expandidas a su valor, mientras que dentro de las comillas simples como `'` el `$` no es un carácter especial y no será expandido).